# inkscape pdf+latex, unclean exit

Tags: pdftex, pdf, svg, inkscape

I have expected this question to be asked before, but searched and no luck. It took some effort to produce this MWE.
I have followed [this](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/svg-inkscape/InkscapePDFLaTeX.pdf) link. When I `pdflatex` compile this, it produces an `exit with code 1` on `Kile`, if it contains latex code. Even though the output file is good.
Why is this unclean `exit`?

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt,twoside]{book}

\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage{epstopdf}

\newcommand{\executeiffilenewer}[3]{%
\ifnum\pdfstrcmp{\pdffilemoddate{#1}}%
{\pdffilemoddate{#2}}>0%
{\immediate\write18{#3}}\fi%
}

\newcommand{\includesvg}[1]{%
\executeiffilenewer{#1.svg}{#1.pdf}%
{inkscape -z -D --file=#1.svg %
--export-pdf=#1.pdf --export-latex}%
\input{#1.pdf_tex}%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[!ht]
 \centering
 \includesvg{bar}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

main.tex: my source code

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx).

Comment: @ClaudioFiandrino , what exactly don't use like about the formatting?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Stumbled on solution while debugging another problem

`\usepackage{xcolor}`

This is not mentioned in the inkscape+pdf [documentation](http://mirrors.ctan.org/info/svg-inkscape/InkscapePDFLaTeX.pdf). I think this can qualify as a bug. But it is hard to encounter since most work would `\includepackage{xcolor}` package for one reason or another. Further, beamer loads `xcolor` by default.

Comment: `xcolor` would be a more *modern* choice. Beamer, TikZ/PGF and many more use xcolor instead.

Comment: works like a charm. Edited answer. Thanx